# $\mathcal{O}$ is finite. If $U,V\in\mathcal{O}$, $U\cap V\in\mathcal{O}$ and $U\cup V\in\mathcal{O}$. Then $(S,\mathcal{O})$ is a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove the following proposition:

> Let $S$ be a set.
> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a finite set whose elements are subsets of $S$.
> Let $\emptyset\in\mathcal{O}$.
> Let $S\in\mathcal{O}$.
> If $U,V\in\mathcal{O}$, then $U\cap V\in\mathcal{O}$.
> If $U,V\in\mathcal{O}$, then $U\cup V\in\mathcal{O}$.
> Then, $(S,\mathcal{O})$ is a topological space.

My proof:

> Since $\mathcal{O}$ is a finite set, we can write $\mathcal{O}=\{O_1,\dots,O_n\}$.
> We must show the following:
> If $U_\lambda\in\mathcal{O}$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, then $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda\in\mathcal{O}$.
> Let $f$ be a function from $\Lambda$ to $\mathcal{O}$ such that $f(\lambda)=O_\lambda$.
> Since $\mathcal{O}$ is a finite set, $f(\Lambda)$ is also a finite set.
> $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f(\lambda)=\bigcup f(\Lambda)$.
> By the mathematical induction, $\bigcup f(\Lambda)\in\mathcal{O}$.

Is my proof ok or not?

Comment: That's fine. ${}{}$

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much for your comment.